# Will this block the io thread and should I use `exchange.isInThread()` logic

Tags: undertow

So I am playing around with implementing my own `Undertow` path and post classes.  I wrote this one class that implements the `HttpHandler` interface.  Pretty straight forward thus far.  My question.  I had to write a `callback` method in order to get access to the post's xml body.  Again, no biggie but... a few questions...

1. This just works without using the test to see if we are in the io thread or not.  Be that as it may, I'm `assuming` that this, then, is a blocking operation and could cause request queueing....yes?
2. From the docs and few examples I found it's explained that you should test to see if you're in the io thread and, if so, call `exchange.startBlocking()`, then dispatch, then exit.  Again ... yes?
3. In my sample code that follows, I have that commented out but it works fine, but I'm thinking this is a no no.....yes?
4. There is, apparently, also a `BlockingHandler` that can be implemented whereby the implementation code would not have to do the test for the io thread and then call `exchange.startBlocking()`...yes?
5. In the sample below I actually just get the `response` out of the callback and then do further processing with `exchange`.  Would it be better if I had the code all in the `callback` handler?

Thank you.

```
  public class ApiTaxwareHandler implements HttpHandler {

      private static final AtomicLong hitCount = new AtomicLong();

      @Override
      public void handleRequest(final HttpServerExchange exchange) throws Exception {
          //
          //  Reading the request body is a BLOCKing operation so
          //  we have to push this thread outside of the io thread
          //  and then we can block it.  the if condition below accomplishes
          // that.
  //        if (exchange.isInIoThread()) {
  //            exchange.startBlocking();
  //            exchange.dispatch(this);
  //            return;
  //        }

          Map<String, Deque<String>> queryParams = exchange.getQueryParameters();
          if (queryParams.isEmpty()) {
              throw new Exception("Parameter 'key' is missing from the request");
          }

          long bytesInBody = exchange.getRequestContentLength();

          //int bytesInBody = exchange.getInputStream().available();
          StringBuilder requestBody = new StringBuilder((int) bytesInBody);

          // Low level gobble-d-gook to fully read the request header.
          exchange.getRequestReceiver().receiveFullString(new Receiver.FullStringCallback() {
              @Override
              public void handle(HttpServerExchange exchange, String message) {
                  //exchange.getResponseSender().send(message);
                  requestBody.append(message);
                  log.debug("Leaving FullStringCallback and setting request body StringBuilder");
              }
          });

          String apiKey = queryParams.get("key").getFirst();
          String xmlIn = requestBody.toString(); //new Scanner(exchange.getInputStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\Z").next();

          log.debug("ApiTaxwareHandler.taxLookupHandler.\nPath is: " + exchange.getRequestPath() + "\nQueryParams are: key=" + apiKey + "\nContent size is: " + bytesInBody + "\nRequest body is " + xmlIn);

          exchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/xml");
          exchange.getResponseSender().send("Responding from " + exchange.getRequestPath() + "  Hit Count now: " + hitCount.incrementAndGet());
      }
```